# Migration of liquibase from 3.5.3 to 4.8.0 on java + spring app

Tags: java, spring, liquibase

Good day!

We have Java + Spring app which run liquibase.
Currently in migration of liquibase from 3.5.5 to 4.8.0 version.
Using next **SpringLiquibase** setup:

```
private static SpringLiquibase liquibase(Properties properties) throws IOException {
        DataSource dataSource = datasource(properties);
        SpringLiquibase liquibase = new SpringLiquibase();
        liquibase.setChangeLog(properties.getProperty("liquibase.masterfile","classpath:master.xml"));
        liquibase.setDataSource(dataSource);
        liquibase.setResourceLoader(new DefaultResourceLoader());
        liquibase.setClearCheckSums(true);
        return liquibase;
    }
```

by setting up **ClearCheckSums** to **true** I'm expecting behaviour like here
https://forum.liquibase.org/t/how-to-recalculate-checksums-without-re-running-the-statements-in-liquibase/5226/4 so rerun of the changeSets should not happens. CheckSums were cleaned up but rerun of scripts triggering anyway.
What do I miss here?